# How can I replace "enter" or a new line with a character using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I have two paragraphs in one cell, and I want to merge the paragraphs together within the cell to form one big paragraph. I also want to replace the "enters" with ` so that I know that this is where the new paragraph used to begin.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim mystring As String
mystring = Cells(1, 1).Value
Cells(1,1) = mystring.Replace(vbCrLf, "`")

End sub
```

However, this code doesn't work and I'm getting different errors.

[image: What I have]
[image: What I need]

Comment: ```Cells(1,1) = Replace(mystring,vbCrLf, "`")```

Comment: or just ```Cells(1,1).Replace(vbCrLf, "`")```

Comment: Do I need to do any dimensioning before that?

Comment: Just note that some controls use different characters. RTF text boxes uses only CR unless you optionally set a flag to say use CRLF. Plain text boxes use LF and ignore CR though will enter CRLF if you press enter.

Comment: The second one would be the only line needed.  The first would replace the third line.

Comment: What's the cell text that is giving errors - and what are the error messages. Your example looks to be working as you expect.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried the second one Cells(1,1).Replace(vbCrLf, "`") but the cell just says "TRUE".

Comment: @ScottCraner Also, while the first method works, the change isn't being reflected on the spreadsheet.

Comment: you do not put `Cells(1,1)=` on the front of that line.  That should be the only text inside the sub

Comment: Then you have something besides `CrLf` see what @user18521918 stated.

Comment: Okay I will try vbCr and vbLf, but also if I don't equate it to anything, I get an "expected =" error.

Comment: @user18521918 By text boxes, do you mean cells?

Comment: Also, can this replace multiple times in one cell?

Comment: This is a list of line break codes you may encounter CR  000D,   LF  000A,   CRLF  000D-000A,   NEL*  0085,   VT  000B,   FF  000C,   LS  2028,   PS  2029.

Comment: Is there a way to retain font formatting like (color and strikethrough) when doing this? Like if one paragraph is red and one is black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retain per-character formatting then you need to use the cell's `Characters` collection to perform the replacement.  It's a bit more work but no too much more.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    DoReplace [B2], vbLf, "`"
End Sub

'Replace all instances of `findWhat` in cell `c`, and repalce
'   with `repalceWith`, preserving any per-character font formatting.
Sub DoReplace(c As Range, findWhat As String, replaceWith As String)
    Dim start As Long, txt, pos As Long
    start = 1
    Do
        pos = InStr(start, c.Value, findWhat, vbTextCompare)
        If pos > 0 Then c.Characters(pos, Len(findWhat)).Text = replaceWith
    Loop While pos > 0
End Sub
```